# Symlinks within a mounted cifs is appearing as directories

Tags: linux, mount, symlink, samba, cifs

I have mounted a cifs(samba) share, and noticed that all the symlinks within the share are being shown as directories in the share. I have set unix extensions = no, in Samba.

Side note, by setting unix extensions = yes, the symlinks do display as expected(symlinks).

Is there a way, I can set unix extension = no, and still maintain my symlinks within the share?

Comment: My guess would be that symbolic links _are_ a unix extension, and therefore not available when those are turned off